Using "the result" vs. "the results" in "the row headings and the column headings specify the operands and the table cells specify the result"
I asked ChatGPT that using "the result" instead of "the results" in the following sentence is correct or not:

For binary operators, a condensed form of truth table is also used,
where the row headings and the column headings specify the operands
and the table cells specify the result.

And ChatGPT's answer is as follows:

The correct version would therefore be:
"Where the row headings and the column headings specify the operands
and the table cells specify the results."
"The result" could only be correct if the focus shifted to each
individual cell, as in:
"Where each table cell specifies the result."
So, in summary:
In the original sentence: "the result" is not correct because it
doesn't match the plural subject "the table cells." To make it
correct, either use "the results" or rephrase to focus on individual
cells with "each table cell specifies the result."

This answer amazes me since I think "the result" and "results" are both correct for this sentence and more or less the same, but "the results" is NOT correct grammatically. ChatGPT gave me the least expected answer which I think is completely wrong.
So, did ChatGPT make the mistake giving the wrong answer here?

"And the corresponding table cell specifies the result".   Row+header intersection is a single cell.  Avoid the futile debate.

Arguably both are correct for this situation, as you said.  However there is a matter of style and consistency.  If you have a sentence that's chock full of plurals, where each noun is listed as a plural, it feels inconsistent and wrong to switch back to singular at the last second "just because you can".

column headings specify the operands and the table cells specify the results.

Or, if you have a preference to use the singular, rearrange the sentence to accommodate that:
"And the corresponding table cell specifies the result"
